# Monostatic range-doppler algorithm

Tags: radar

I was told that this question is too broad. Maybe I don't understand what this forum is about. My question is basically the same. I am looking for references to range Doppler algorithms so I can learn how they work. I said monostatic radar because it is probably the most basic radar system. If someone can help, fine. Else, I'll keep looking on my own. Still very appreciative.

I am looking for radar range-Doppler algorithms, especially for monostatic radars, used to create range-Doppler maps. I am looking into books and papers, and I checked the internet. There is much talk about RDA (Radar-Doppler algorithm) and RDM (Radar-Doppler map) but I cannot find any documents or code which are tutorial in nature.

Comment: Your question is very general. Do you have any specific questions? Radar range maps are a very broad topic. Too broad for anyone to be able to answer specifically.  And, while `reference-request` is a valid tag here, you haven't really framed the question like that.

Comment: I believe the question is still too broad, but I will reopen to see whether the community has anything to add.

Comment: The basic principles of range-Doppler radar are simple: you transmit some signal (either CW or pulsed) and look for reflections from distant targets. You deduce the range to the target via the observed time delay in the reflection. You can deduce radial velocity from the target to you via the observed Doppler shift in the reflection as well. That's it! As always, the devil is in the details. What specifically are you looking for information on? If you just need broad knowledge on radar techniques, you're best off going to a reference text.

Comment: As for me M. A. Richards ' Fundamentals of radar signal processing ' is pretty awesome book to start from. When I faced radar DSP after some wireless communication experience, it was really helpful. Try it for example. But as you've been told the topic is pretty large to gain a simple answer, probably some lecture course will be fine)